# Bokmarks manager plugin for Firefox

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I need some plugin or anything for firefox v22 so I could place all my bookmarks on the left side of the screen. Bookmark list should be editable, scrollable, in tree-view and abc sortable. Could someone recommend me something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [StartAid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/online-bookmark-manager-starta/).

> The Online Bookmark extension allows you to access all your personal
>   online bookmarks from within your Firefox browser.

[image]

Comment: @Bonaca: I hope it works for you.